# How to do the "Sketch colorization" like Project Scribbler using Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, color, computer-vision

Recently, the Adobe release the Project Scribbler
[Adobe Max 2017](https://research.adobe.com/project/scribbler-controlling-deep-image-synthesis-with-sketch-and-color/).
[image]

The picture is from the P. Sangkloy, J. Lu, C. Fang, F. Yu and J. Hays. [Scribbler: Controlling Deep Image Synthesis with Sketch and Color](http://scribbler.eye.gatech.edu/paper.pdf). CVPR 2017.

It can generate a color pictures based on the sketch. How can we build a similar function in Mathematica which can colorize the picture like the sketch colorization in the Project Scribbler.

One of my simple idea is to use the slope rate of the lines. The region where exists the vertical lines is different color with the region where exists the horizontal lines. Another is that based on the density of lines. Regions with different density of lines have different colors. But how to use the functions in Mathematica to develop such function?

Comment: You can try to get the `MorphologicalComponents` of the image for colorization, but my guess is that will be too rough to really wrk with. Also if you skim their paper, they seem to be using neural nets to do their work, so you'll need to build and train a neural network of your own. Doing this without one seems semi-intractable.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the "sketch" is secondary here. Once you master general colorization you can try adopting it for sketches. Potentially you can experiment with training data and neural net structures. I will point you to 3 things that serve as starting points.

#### 1. [LINK](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-Places-Data-Raw-Model): ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on Places Data (Raw Model)

```
NetModel["ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on Places Data (Raw Model)"]
```

#### 2. [LINK](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data-Raw-Model_1): ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition Data (Raw Model)

```
NetModel["ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition Data (Raw Model)"]
```

#### 3. [LINK](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1210907): Wolfram Summer School Project: Image Colorization

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the closest built-in command is Image Restyle. Start with one of the sketches above and four of the photos (not including the "ground truth" photo for the chosen sketch). Then image restyling gives something vaguely plausible, (maybe more like a watercolor than a photograph).

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAppQ.png"]
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLZYk.png"]
ImageRestyle[img1, img2]
```

[image]